# WSUS 3.2 Showing "No Status" for Forefront Enpoint Protection even though we already have a corporate virus protection

Tags: wsus

I'm a bit confused why a number of our machines are showing a number of updates related to Microsoft Endpoint Protection even though it's not apparent that Forefront or Security Essentials is installed.  I double checked to see if either were installed.  We currently have Kaspersky as our main AV solution.  How do I remove this clutter properly?  Why would these machines think they need these updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it showing "No Status"?  That doesn't mean it thinks the update's applicable, it means the machine hasn't checked in since the update was downloaded by WSUS; if that's the case, this is to be expected.  Which view of updates are you looking at?

If you aren't looking to use those updates at all, then you might as well just disable the downloading of the Forefront Endpoint updates to get rid of the noise - in options under products and classifications:

[image]

Comment: I think this will do it!  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.